# Selenium Webscraper Click doesn't work on Morningstar

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, web-scraping

I want to access a Morningstar link such as "https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/quote" using Selenium Webscraper, but on Firefox, an ad pops up and I want the webscraper to click the "Continue to Site" button so then I can access the financial data.

I've tried using

```
exchange = "xnas"
ticker = "aapl"
url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/' + exchange + '/' + ticker + '/quote' 
driver.get(url)    
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.mdc-button.mds-button.mds-button--flat').click()
```

but then I get the error that

```
Message: Element <button class="mdc-button mds-button default-layout__nav-toggle mds-button--icon-only mds-button--flat mds-button--flat-icon-m" type="button"> is not clickable at point (31,34) because another element <div class="mdc-masthead__inner mds-masthead__inner"> obscures it
```

I've also tried using Actions or execute_script and neither of those throw errors, but Firefox doesn't continue onto the site and the ad is still present.

Please help, 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using webdriver manager. Then your code works fine for me:

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

exchange = "xnas"
ticker = "aapl"
url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/' + exchange + '/' + ticker + '/quote' 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.mdc-button.mds-button.mds-button--flat')
button.click()
```

The side menu bar then opens.

Hope this helps?